# Is there some necessary reason about design a method in this way

Tags: java, data-structures

I am reading Sedgewick's Algorithms 4th. there is an excise on Page 165

> Write a method `remove()`  that takes a linked list and a string key as arguments and removes all of the nodes in the list that have key as its item field.

I think the linked list argument is redundant, because as an instance method always invokes with the object name. So why does the author want it to be passed as a argument? (I don't think writing remove() as a static method is better than a instance method.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You dont have to think of this `remove` method as a member of your `LinkedList` class at all.  It could be a method in a utility class that works on the objects that get passed in.